# Spark spark.shuffle.memoryFraction has no affect

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, emr

I am testing Spark on Amazon EMR using Python and the basic [wordcount example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/wordcount.py) shipped with Spark.

After running the application, I realized that in Stage 0 reduceByKey(add), around 2.5GB shuffle is spilled to memory and 4GB shuffle is spilled to disk. Since in the wordcount example I am not caching or persisting any data, so I thought I can increase the performance of this application by giving more shuffle memoryFraction. So, in spark-defaults.conf, I added the following:

```
spark.storage.memoryFraction    0.2
spark.shuffle.memoryFraction    0.6
```

However, I am still getting the same performance and the same amount of shuffle data is being spilled to disk and memory. I validated that Spark is reading these configurations using Spark UI/Environment and I can see my changes. Moreover, I tried setting `spark.shuffle.spill` to false and I got the performance I am looking for and all shuffle data was spilled to memory only.

So, what am I getting wrong here and why not the extra shuffle memory fraction is not utilized?

My environment:
Amazon EMR with Spark 1.3.1 running using -x argument
1 Master node: m3.xlarge
3 Core  nodes: m3.xlarge
Application: wordcount.py
Input: 10 .gz files 90MB each (~350MB unarchived) stored in S3
Submit command:

```
/home/hadoop/spark/bin/spark-submit --deploy-mode client /mnt/wordcount.py s3n://<input location>
```

spark-defaults.conf:

```
spark.eventLog.enabled          false
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions   -Dspark.driver.log.level=INFO
spark.master                    yarn
spark.executor.instances        3
spark.executor.cores            4
spark.executor.memory           9404M
spark.default.parallelism       12
spark.eventLog.enabled          true
spark.eventLog.dir              hdfs:///spark-logs/
spark.storage.memoryFraction    0.2
spark.shuffle.memoryFraction    0.6
```

Comment: Also, in 1.3, `spark.shuffle.spill=false` sometimes has no effect.  Not sure what's going on and whether it's something specific to EMR Spark 1.3.